# FB Login Button Throws Access_Token Null or Undefined Today

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I have a fielded FB application which uses the JS login button workflow ("fb:login-button").  Users of my FB application are receiving the following error which breaks login:

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'access_token': object is null or undefined`.

This error occurs after the pop-up appears and they enter their credentials.

I am not aware of changing any authentication-related code on my end.  Has something changed in the FB response token?

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Are you using deprecated auth flows? The default was switched to Oauth 2 today - the deadline was Oct 1st, here's a sample blog post outlining some of the changes from July: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Comment: Strange coincidence -- I am already using OAuth 2.0.  Interestingly, I can login fine with the authentication workflow using localhost -- but it fails in production.

Comment: It's working again -- without any coding changes on my end.  I blame Facebook -- I've had issues with reliability of the APIs in the past.

Comment: How do I close this -- i.e. "it was a facebook issue".  I would like to keep this around for others who may experience the same issue.

Comment: @Shaun: post answer yourself and than you can accept it later to mark it as answered.No need to close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async function, `FB.getLoginStatus`, returns `response.session.access_token`.
Throughout the day the response object changed to `response.authResponse.accessToken`.  This seemingly random change in the response object from Facebook caused the application to fail.  At around 5PM CST the signature changed back to `response.session.access_token`.  As of 11:45 PM CST the signature is `response.authResponse.accessToken`.

Comment: It's not really random, the change was scheduled for October 1st and was flagged several times since May -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ links to some of the blog posts and gives a summary of the changes