# facebook login throws Oauth Exception (certificate non found)

Tags: facebook

it looks like my problems with facebook (and twitter) never end, and it is certainly my fault.

I had a facebook app that was working properly. Today all of a sudden it stopped working. The cURL response is empty, the POST if you try does nothing or throws an OAuth excetion, and the only error I get when I get something is that the SSL certificate can't be found. It worked until some hours ago, so I really wonder what the problem is. 
Even the login button seems to give the same error. Any clues on what I am doing wrong and/or should have updated some hours ago to get things going?
I tried to disable the SSL, following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495884/fb-login-button-throws-access-token-null-or-undefined-today), but it's still not working...

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to resolve this too, although the solution isn't the best option, so, if  someone has a more elaborate solution, I'll be glad to take notes.
For the moment, I was forced to add to the facebook php library (updated of course), and not to the page that is doing the job, the line

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);`

I wouldn't say it is an ideal solution though.